# Microsoft Publisher 2016 won't open the file I created in Microsoft Publisher

Tags: microsoft-publisher

I am using Microsoft Publisher 2016 in Windows 10.

Microsoft Publisher 'detected a problem' with the Publisher file I created after many hours of work and saved, and won't open it.

I used CTRL-SHIFT-I to get the error code 1100931.

How can I repair the file, or make Publisher open it?

Comment: 3000 views, no upvotes or comments! Hopefully this was useful to someone! :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928890/publisher-cannot-open-the-file-or-publisher-has-detected-a-problem-err) on Microsoft Support:

### Important

Follow the step carefully. Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you modify it, back up the registry for restoration in case problems occur.

1. Exit Publisher.
2. Click Start, click Run, type regedit in the Open box, and then click OK.
3. Locate and then select the following registry key:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Publisher
4. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
5. Type PromptForBadFiles, and then press ENTER.
6. Right-click PromptForBadFiles, and then click Modify.
7. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
8. On the File menu, click Exit to exit Registry Editor.